# mysql select only unique values which has not been assigned to any other

Tags: mysql

My database looks something like this

```
id document_id resource_id language filename
1   11          120         English     abc
2   13          120         German      ghy
3   56          120         Norway      hyu
4   56          156         Norway      hyu
5   89          134         Hindi       uiy
6   90          120         English     qwer
```

In this I want to get all the values for resource_id 120. So I can make a query like

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE resource_id = 120
```

But as you can see in the table there is one column for document_id and if you check closer then you can see that the document_id 56 is assigned for two resources. One for 120 and another for 156. So can some one tell me how to check this in mysql sub query.

So my output will be it will show all the data only for resource_id 120. If any other resource is assigned with any document_id which has been shared with resource_id 120 it will be not shown. So only unique data for only 120 resource_id should be shown.

So I have made my query so far like

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE resource_id = 120 
   AND `document_id` IN("SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE  `resource_id` <> 120 ")
```

So can someone tell me how to get the value? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Have a read about JOINs

Comment: so you need records 1,2 and 6, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    resource_id = 120
AND document_id NOT IN (SELECT document_id FROM `table` WHERE resource_id <> 120);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers state, you can just use NOT IN:

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM `table` t            
 WHERE t.resource_id = :id 
   AND t.document_id NOT IN (
    SELECT document_id
      FROM `table`
     WHERE resource_id != t.resource_id
       )
```

However, you may get better performance with NOT EXISTS as you are not SELECTing the id for comparison:

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM `table` t            
 WHERE t.resource_id = :id 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM `table`
     WHERE document_id = t.document_id 
       AND resource_id != t.resource_id
       )
```

Alternatively, there is the LEFT JOIN option, searching for rows that do not match:

```
    SELECT t.* 
      FROM `table` t            
 LEFT JOIN `table` t1
        ON t1.document_id = t.document_id 
       AND t1.resource_id != t.resource_id
     WHERE t.resource_id = :id 
       AND t1.id IS NULL
```

I'd probably choose whichever of the bottom two you find more readable.